# Request-Reply in java network programming

Tags: java, network-programming

I am trying to teach myself Java network programming.

Here's an attempt to implement request-response:

Server:

```
public class SimpleServer1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException 
    {
        ServerSocket sSock = new ServerSocket(8888);

        System.out.println("++++++++++++ started server ++++++++++++");
        System.out.println("++++++++++++ waiting for connections ++++++++++++");
        Socket curConn = sSock.accept();

        // get output stream to dispatch to client

        OutputStream os  = curConn.getOutputStream();
        PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(os);

        // get input stream to read from the client

        InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(curConn.getInputStream());
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);

        pw.write(" ++++++++++++ HandShake from Server ++++++++++++");
        pw.flush();

        while(true)
        {
            System.out.println("in server loop :");
            String curClientInput = br.readLine();
            if(curClientInput.equals("Bye"))
            {
                break;
            }
            pw.write("I am your Server : " + curClientInput);
            pw.flush();
        }

        System.out.println("++++++++++++ shutting down server ++++++++++++");

        br.close();
        isr.close();

        pw.close();
        os.close();
    }

}
```

Client:

```
public class SimpleClient1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws UnknownHostException, IOException
    {
        Socket sock = new Socket("localhost", 8888);
        System.out.println(" ++++ Connecting to server ++++");

        InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(sock.getInputStream());
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);

        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(sock.getOutputStream());

        System.out.println(" ++++ connected to server ++++");

        while(true)
        {
            System.out.println("Entered client loop :");

            // reading response from server
            String response = br.readLine();

            System.out.println("Server says : " + response);

            // dispatching to server
            out.write("Hey you server !!!");
            out.flush();

            if(response.equalsIgnoreCase("bye"))
            {
                break;
            }
        }

        out.close();
        br.close();
        isr.close();
    }

}
```

When I run these here's what I see:

```
Server:
++++++++++++ started server ++++++++++++
++++++++++++ waiting for connections ++++++++++++
in server loop :

Client:
 ++++ Connecting to server ++++
Entered client loop :
```

I am not able to figure out what's going wrong here.Client and Server are stuck at `br.readLine();` Are they deadlocked ?

Answer (score 0):

br.readLine(): it reads a line of text. From documentation: "Reads a line of text. A line is considered to be terminated by any one of a line feed ('\n'), a carriage return ('\r'), or a carriage return followed immediately by a linefeed."

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html

In the server, write '\n' at the end.